# Auto goto active line TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have used TeXstudio for some time. Since my computer crashed the other day, I had to reinstall it.

After I have reinstalled TeXstudio it have stopped automatically going to the active line.
Previously it would automatic go to the active line in the `pdf`, that the cursor was on in the `tex` file. A function I really much enjoyed, but it have stopped doing this now.

Anyone aware of how to reactivate this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the option `-synctex=1` to the compiler. See the Configuration Window.

[image]

Comment: I have the following options in the PDFLatex line. So i can't add -synctex=1 in it. 

pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: @Martin, are you using the internal viewer or the external one?

Comment: Synctex may have problems with spaces or accented characters in the path or filename. Do you have any of those?

Comment: Okay, i found the error.
@TimHoffmann it was the path, i'm from Denmark, and it is a shared folder which contained a 'æ', i wasn't aware of this problem. So thanks for the help, both of you :)